# serializedObject FindProperty retuns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am trying to get a generic list property in editor, but I am getting null though I have initialized it already in target script.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
   public List<Bot<BotType1>> Bots = new List<BotCar<BotType1>>();
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(GameManager))]
GameManagerEditor : Editor
{
   private SerializedProperty botsProperty;

   void OnEnable()
   {
      botsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("Bots");
   }
}
```

I am getting `botsProperty` as null.

Comment: Where does `serializedObject` come from? Could you post the code where you assigned it?

Comment: `serializedObject` is a property of `UnityEditor.Editor`, the parent class of `GameManagerEditor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity can serialize only Lists of a serializable type - from [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

Your list public `List<Bot<BotType1>> Bots` derives from `Bot<T>` that has generic parameter, this means it is not serializable. Meaninging that the class in your list `Bot<BotType1>` is not set as Serializable anywhere.

To achieve your result you should set it as Serializable.

```
[Serializable] public class BotOfType1 : Bot<BotType1>{}
```

Then your list will become:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
   public List<BotOfType1> Bots = new List<BotOfType1>();
}
```

Comment: `List<Bot<BotType1>>`  is a list of `Bot` which is a serializable type also the `BotType1` is serializable.

Comment: As much as I know you cannot serialize a class using the Unity serializer if it has fields with generics. And Bot<T> is generic. The solution I just added to the answer should be working.

Comment: However I'd need to manually assign all the `BotOfType1` properties to `BotType1` properties.

Comment: What do you mean, they are 2 different classes one is a BotType1, the other is BotOfType1? You can assign one or the other, not one TO the other.